# PROBLEM OF ABSTRACT, about Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be an integral ring which contains the field as a sub-ring. Suppose that R is a vector space on k (under the multiplication of the ring). Show that R is a field.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Not true: Take $R=k[X]$ for any field $k$.

It is true if $R$ is finite-dimensional as a vector space over $k$.

Indeed, take $r \in R, r\ne 0$, and consider the map $x \mapsto rx$. This is an injective $k$-linear transformation and so is surjective. Therefore, there is $s \in R$ such that $rs=1$.